# Which standard wording tells us that ref-to-const temporary lifetime extension only "works once"?

Tags: c++

I was shown the following example in chat:

```
#include <iostream>
struct foo { ~foo() { std::cout << "destroying!\n"; } };
const foo& func(const foo& a, const foo&) { return a; }

int main()
{
  foo x;
  const foo& y = func(foo(), x);
  std::cout << "main\n";
}
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/TebAdJ):

```
destroying!
main
destroying!
```

It appears to demonstrate that the lifetime of the `foo` temporary is not extended to entirety of `main`, even though it gets bound to a ref-to-`const` in that scope.

Presumably, then, the lifetime extension only "works once"; that is, it is applied when `func`'s arguments are initialised, but isn't passed on through consecutive bindings.

Is my interpretation correct? If so (and if any individual paragraph is directly applicable) what's the standard wording that defines this behaviour?

Comment: What’s the second argument to `func` for? What happens if you leave it (and `x`) off?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It's for demonstrating destruction order relative to the output of the text `"main"`, I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is subject of two issue reports, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1299 and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1568 .

The former issue report, of which I am the reporter, was intended to cover all these cases where a reference is bound to a temporary object, but is not intended to be lifetime-extending. The description in the body of the issue only mentions prvalues being confused with temporary expressions (that actually decide whether lifetime of what they evaluate to is lengthened or not). But lvalue and xvalues are likewise confused with these in the Standard. An example where that happens in the context of `static_cast` is issue number #1568 (in which the use of "temporary variable" further confuses the matter).

Actually, this:

> A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.

Contradicts the other rules in the same paragraph. Because the temporary is bound to *both* a reference parameter in a function call and to a local automatic reference variable.

Comment: Yeah, ok, you and James have convinced me that the word "except" doesn't disambiguate the paragraph's rules, because the "except" is still only being applied to a single scenario at a time, and as such cannot disambiguate two or more conflicting scenarios.

Answer (score 9):

You're almost right. This behaviour actually comes from the function call specifically, not because of any sort of "only works once" rule.

Here's the wording for the whole lifetime extension "feature", with the pertinent rule emphasised in bold:

> `[C++11: 12.2/5]:` *[..]* The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference **except**:
>
> - *[..]*
> - **A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.**
> - *[..]*

Comment: But in this case, the temporary is also bound to the const reference `y`.  So which reference controls its lifetime?

Comment: @JamesKanze: I see the "except" list as taking precedence.

Comment: I sort of see what you mean, but I still think it's ambiguous, and if that's the intent, a bit of a torturous way of specifying it.  First, you guarantee an extended lifetime based uniquely on whether the reference is bound to a temporary or not, then you eliminate all of the cases which could lead to an indirection, hoping you've gotten them all (which they probably haven't).

Comment: On further analysis, and considering all of the text, I'm pretty sure that this was not the intent of the committee.  If so, they missed a number of cases.  Consider `void f() { Foo const& f1 = Foo(); static Foo const& f2 = f1; }`.  What should be the lifetime of the temporary `Foo()`.  It is clearly bound to `f2`, and none of the cases following the "except" enter into consideration.  There's clearly a bug in the standard.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yeah, maybe. I think the _intent_ is that the lifetime is extended only when the temporary is bound to a reference and not when "a reference is bound to a reference" (yes, I know.. hence the quote marks), i.e. basically what I said in the question. It doesn't say that atm though. Worth looking into further.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the intent is for the lifetime to be extended _only_ when the expression generating the temporary is used to initialize the reference.  Otherwise, you end up with all sorts of lifetime issues, with the compiler having to do extensive analysis (and maybe introduce extra flags---in my function `f`, the first time through the temporary would have static lifetime, but the second not).  The problem is formulating it correctly.  I'll raise the issue with the committee, if I don't forget.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yeah, that's what I meant :P I'll get Ville to mention it too if I run into him

Answer (score 3):

The rule which applies here is common sense.  The standard is
poorly worded, and does in fact guarantee this.  But there's no
practical way to implement it.

Comment: What do you mean? No practical way to implement the restriction, or to implement the lifetime extension that doesn't presently happen?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There is no practical way of forcing the lifetime of a temporary to extend to the last reference it's bound to.

Comment: I think @James is talking about what I summarize in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably I am a bit slow but to me it did not become clear what the resolution of this question is from reading the other answers. Thus I modified the code shown and wanted to summarize for others: the answer is, you get **undefined behavior** if you access `y`!

Run this code:

```
struct foo {
    int id;
    foo(int id) : id(id) { std::cout << "ctor " << id << std::endl; };
    ~foo() { std::cout << "dtor " << id << std::endl; }
};
const foo& func(const foo& a, const foo&) { return a; }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    foo x(1);
    const foo& y = func(foo(2), x);
    std::cout << "main " << y.id << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output for me is:

```
ctor 1
ctor 2
dtor 2
main 2
dtor 1
```

But the line `main 2` is **undefined behavior**.