# Lifetime of temporary passed through function by reference

Tags: c++

I can do something like this:

```
const int &i = 5;
```

and have the lifetime of the temporary extended to the lifetime of `i`.

But how about

```
const int &fun (const int &i){
    return i;
}

int main () {
    const int &r = fun(5);
    // Can I use r here?
}
```

Is the lifetime of the proxy-5 still extended? Or is `r` a dangling reference?

Comment: 5 is an rvalue.  The function will create a temporary for you, but then delete it after the function is over.  So yes, this is a dangling reference.

Comment: Possible almost-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14735630/560648

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why "almost"?

Comment: @Barry: I think it's one of those "touches the same subject and basically asks the same question but isn't a 'duplicate'" situations :P Since that original question was mine I didn't want to seem improper.

Comment: Well the "dupe" has answers that answer my question. But I would not have come up with the wording "only works once".

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Indeed, it was not a good question :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a dangling reference. From [class.temporary]/4-5:

> There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the fullexpression.
>   The first context is when a default constructor is called [ ... ]
>
> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is
>   bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists
>   for the lifetime of the reference except:
>
> - A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s *ctor-initializer* [ ...]
> - A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists **until the completion of
>     the full-expression containing the call**.
> - [...]

The `5` persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call, which is to say:

```
const int &r = fun(5);
// <== no more 5
```

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't believe so. You bound `5` to the reference that's the argument to `fun`, so it lasts for as long as that argument lasts. The argument only lasts for the duration of the call to `fun`.

The relevant standard text was explored in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14738884/560648).