# Avoid returning by-reference argument

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a class `Option`:

```
template<typename T>
class Option {
public:
    Option() noexcept
    {}

    Option(T val) noexcept : val_(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(val)))
    {}

    const T & get() const
    {
        if (val_ == nullptr) {
            throw std::out_of_range("get on empty Option");
        }
        return *val_;
    }

    const T & getOrElse(const T &x) const
    {
        return val_ == nullptr ? x : *val_;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> val_;
};
```

The argument passed to `Option::getOrElse` is the default value to return when this `Option` is empty:

```
Option<int> x;  // empty
int y = 123;
x.getOrElse(y);  // == 123
```

However, I think the following code is not safe:

```
Option<int> x;
x.getOrElse(123);  // reference to temporary variable!
```

A safer way would be to return by value from `Option::getOrElse`, but that would be wasteful when the `Option` is non-empty. Can I work around this somehow?

**UPDATE:** I'm thinking about perhaps overloading on the argument type (lvalue/rvalue) of `getOrElse`, but haven't figured out exactly how to do so.

**UPDATE 2:** Maybe this?

```
T getOrElse(T &&x) const { ... }

const T & getOrElse(const T &x) const { ... }
```

But I think this might be ambiguous because both lvalue and rvalue arguments fit the second version.

Comment: Why are you returning anything?  If it is a check of success or failure you could return a `bool`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm not sure what you mean...? `getOrElse` is a getter with a default value.

Comment: I do not see a default value in your code.  Are you trying to combine a getter and setter in a single function?

Comment: This is legal but an obvious pitfall is that it is easy for the caller to create a dangling reference, as you show in your last code sample

Comment: @NathanOliver No, `x.getOrElse(y)` returns the value held by `x` if `x` is not empty, otherwise it returns y.

Comment: @NathanOliver `getOrElse` is pretty common in languages with optional values. `auto x = foo.getOrElse(bar)` will set `x` to `bar` if the getter returns a nully value. It'll set `x` to the returned value otherwise.

Comment: See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional/value_or).

Comment: @JamesAdkison @erip I'm aware of `std::optional`, but returning by value is exactly what stops me from using that. It's not viable for move-only or expensive-to-copy classes.

Comment: returning by value is what you want with move-only classes, isn't it?

Comment: another problem is that even reference to `*val_` may dangle, e.g. `auto& ref = Option<int>(5).getOrElse(y);` .  You will have to document that the caller should not assign the return value of this expression to anything  (I don't think it's possible to enforce that with code)

Comment: @xaxxon My move-only I mean classes like `std::unique_ptr`, which you can't return by value.

Comment: Why not?   Works for me: https://godbolt.org/g/6xLkx2  -- but you can't make a copy of it, you ... have to move it, because it's move only.

Comment: @ZizhengTai You can certainly return move only classes by value.

Comment: @xaxxon @BaummitAugen https://godbolt.org/g/5Eb5F1 This is what I mean; the `Option` class itself is not supposed to be mutated by a _getter_.

Comment: Yes, you can't make a copy of a unique_ptr.. it wouldn't be unique anymore.  That isn't because of the return type, per se.  It's' because you're trying to make a copy, not move it.

Comment: @ZizhengTai Ah, yes I see. I'll have a look at this tomorrow if no one answers it.

Comment: See https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063211/why-does-most-important-const-have-to-be-const also.

Comment: @xaxxon Can you take a look at my second update?

Comment: "But I think this might be ambiguous because both lvalue and rvalue arguments fit the second version." No, quite the opposite.

Comment: @ZizhengTai it is not ambiguouse, in the same way as having a move constructor `T(T&&)` is not ambigouse if you also have a copy constructor `T(const T&)`

Answer (score 4):

> However, I think the following code is not safe:
>
> ```
> Option<int> x;
> x.getOrElse(123);  // reference to temporary variable!
> ```

You are correct. This is why `std::optional::value_or()` returns a `T` and not a `T&` or `T const&`. As per the rationale in [N3672](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3672.html#rationale.value_or):

> It has been argued that the function should return by constant reference rather than value, which would avoid copy overhead in certain situations:
>
> ```
> void observe(const X& x);
>
> optional<X> ox { /* ... */ };
> observe( ox.value_or(X{args}) );    // unnecessary copy
> ```
>
> However, the benefit of the function value_or is only visible when the optional object is provided as a temporary (without the name); otherwise, a ternary operator is equally useful:
>
> ```
> optional<X> ox { /* ... */ };
> observe(ox ? *ok : X{args});            // no copy
> ```
>
> Also, returning by reference would be likely to render a dangling reference, in case the optional object is disengaged, because the second argument is typically a temporary:
>
> ```
> optional<X> ox {nullopt};
> auto&& x = ox.value_or(X{args});
> cout << x;                              // x is dangling!
> ```

I suggest you follow the same guidelines. If you really need to avoid the copy, use a ternary. This is safe and copyless:

```
Optional<int> ox = ...;
const int& val = ox ? *ox : 123;
```

If you really don't, or the `Optional` is an rvalue anyway, `getOrElse()`  is more concise.

Comment: I don't understand why you said his example isn't safe -- or what the rational is for not returning a const&.   I read what you pasted twice but still don't get it.

Comment: >  returning by reference would be likely to render a dangling reference, in case the optional object is disengaged -- I don't know what "disengaged" means.

Comment: @xaxxon By "disengaged" I think Barry means "empty".

Comment: @xaxxon If you pass in a temporary, its lifetime wouldn't get extended through the function. You end up with a dangling reference

Comment: Is something like `int x = emptyInt.getOrElse(123);` safe if `123` is passed in by const-reference?

Comment: @Zizheng Yes. And trivially so if that function jus returned a value as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Since users of your class can expect the reference returned from `Option::get()` to be valid only as along as the the particular instance of the `Option` object's lifetime, you could reasonably make the same expectation for what is returned from `Option::getOrElse()`.

In that case it might be an acceptable overhead for the object to maintain a collection of things that it needs to keep alive for the client:

```
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Option {
public:
    Option() noexcept
    {}

    Option(T val) noexcept : val_(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(val)))
    {}

    const T & get() const
    {
        if (val_ == nullptr) {
            throw std::out_of_range("get on empty Option");
        }
        return *val_;
    }

    const T & getOrElse(const T &x) const
    {
        if (val_ == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "storing const T &\n";
            elses_.push_front(x);
            return elses_.front();
        }

        return *val_;
    }

    const T & getOrElse(T &&x) const
    {
        if (val_ == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "storing T && by move\n";
            elses_.push_front(std::move(x));
            return elses_.front();
        }

        return *val_;
    }


private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> val_;
    mutable std::list<T> elses_;
};


int main()
{
    Option<int> x;  // empty
    int y = 123;
    auto rx = x.getOrElse(y);  // == 123

    auto & rxx = x.getOrElse(42); 

    std::cout << "rx = " << rx << "\n";
    std::cout << "rxx = " << rxx << "\n";
}
```

The references returned by `Option::getOrElse()` will be valid for as long as the reference returned from `Option::get()` would be.  Of course, this also means that `Option::getOrElse()` can throw an exception.

As a small improvement, if the `T` type can be used as keys for an associative container you could use one of those instead of a `std::list` and easily avoid storing duplicates.

Comment: Interesting approach!

Comment: Do we really need to store `const T &`s in `elses_` also?

Comment: For solving a non-existent problem in one member function, you're proposing the type store a *whole extra container* and now `getOrElse()` potentially does memory allocation?!

Comment: @Barry: admittedly this was an idea that came after only few minutes of thought. I'm not proposing it for the standard library or boost. And while `observe(ox ? *ox : X{args}))` might avoid overhead that you feel is unacceptable, it comes with its own cost of being arguably less obvious and maybe more error-prone than `observe( ox.getOrElse(X{args}))`. For instance, needing to repeat the name of the `optional` object might lead to errors such as in the example from n3672 that has a typo: `observe(ox ? *ok : X{args})` should be ``observe(ox ? *ox : X{args})``

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest to re-design this class?

It has a default ctor which can leave the val_ to be nullptr, but it has a get() at the same time which may throw exception because of dereference (*). It also designed to save T in shared_prt but return it as reference.

Let the client to know it's null:

```
template<typename T>
class Option {
public:
    Option() noexcept
    {}

    Option(T val) noexcept : val_(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(val)))
    {}

    const T & get() const
    {
        return *val_;
    }

    bool IsNull() const
    {
        return val_ == nullptr;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> val_;
};
```

The client code changed from:

```
Option option;
const T & ref = option.getOrElse(123);
```

to be:

```
Option option;
const T & ref = option.IsNull() ? 123 : option.get();
```

Why I delete the: if (val_ == nullptr) {

Let's make make_shared<> clear:

1. return a valid pointer, or
2. throw bad_alloc exception; **it does not return null**

So IsNull() is also useless, it should be like:

```
template<typename T>
class Option {
public:
    Option(T val) noexcept : val_(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(val)))
    {}

    const T & get() const
    {
        return *val_;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> val_;
};
```

Why to use shared_ptr? option objects can be move or copied several times? or else I prefer to design it like:

```
template<typename T>
class Option {
public:
    Option(T val) noexcept : val_(std::move(val))
    {}

    const T & get() const
    {
        return val_;
    }

private:
    T val_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather return by reference and let the caller decide, whether he wants to store a reference to or a copy of the returned value.