# C++11 move to local const reference: scope

Tags: c++, scope, reference, constants, move

For regular local const reference variables, the scope is [prolonged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784304/1403469).  Which is why the following code works as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct foo
{
        foo()
        {
                std::cout << "foo() @" << (void*)this << std::endl;
        }
        ~foo()
        {
                std::cout << "~foo() @" << (void*)this << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
        auto const& f = std::make_shared<foo>();
        std::cout << "f = " << f.get() << std::endl;
        return 0;
}

// prints:
// foo() @0x55f249c58e80
// f = 0x55f249c58e80
// ~foo() @0x55f249c58e80
```

It seems though that this does not work as expected when assigning a moved object using `std::move()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <list>

struct foo
{
        foo()
        {
                std::cout << "foo() @" << (void*)this << std::endl;
        }
        ~foo()
        {
                std::cout << "~foo() @" << (void*)this << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
        std::list<std::shared_ptr<foo>> l;
        l.push_back(std::make_shared<foo>());
        auto const& f = std::move(l.front());
        l.clear();
        std::cout << "f = " << f.get() << std::endl;
        return 0;
}

// prints
// foo() @0x564edb58fe80
// ~foo() @0x564edb58fe80
// f = 0x564edb58fe80
```

Does `std::move()` indeed change the scope, or am I dealing with a compiler bug?

Changing the variable from `auto const& f` to just `auto f` fixes the problem.  If I wrap the move into another function, it also works:

```
auto const& f = [&]() { return std::move(l.front()); }();
```

It's almost like `std::move()` does not share the same semantics as a function call, but rather as if it was just a regular variable assignment:

```
auto const& f = std::move(l.front());
```

Comment: You misunderstand `std::move` but I'm not sure how exactly. `std::move` has no effect in any of the examples you've shown, except maybe to disable some optimizations. `std::move` is just a cast from `T&` to `T&&`, it converts lvalue references to rvalue references.

Comment: "when assigning a moved object using std::move()" looks like it is necessary to repeat to some people again and again: `std::move()` itself does not move anything

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it does affect t see my answer

Comment: I realize it doesn't have any effect in this particular sample.  I was actually moving an object from a `std::list` element into a local const reference variable, then deleting the entry from the list, and expected the variable to still be valid.

Comment: I updated the second snippet in my question with what I actually encountered.  Moving an element out of a `std::list` using `std::move()`.  Changing `auto const& f` to `auto f` fixes it, but at the same time I would have expected the same behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver: This is not a duplicate of a version-specific question concerning C++03, because `std::move` didn't exist in C++03.  It probably still is a duplicate, just that target doesn't work.

Comment: @BenVoigt `std::move` is doing the exact same thing.  Do we really need a pre and post C++11 dupe for passing the temporary to a function by reference stops the lifetime extension?

Comment: Related, but also pre-rvalue references: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14735630/103167

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes, because the rule changed dramatically, you need a question about the C++11-and-later rule.

Comment: Well, we both get a vote.  I for one don'y think it has changed, at least not for this scenario.

Comment: @BenVoigt Did you note that the answer in the linked to dupe is referencing the C++11 standard when they quote *A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.*

Comment: @Tom it is not possible to "move an element into a const reference variable". A reference variable refers to some other object, it doesn't contain an object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's put aside `std::move()` and create this function:

```
struct sometype {};

const sometype &foobar( const sometype &cref ) { return cref; }
```

and now we use it:

```
const sometype &ref = foobar( sometype() );
```

What do you think, will lifetime of temporary be prolongated in this case? No it would not. Lifetime is only prolongated when you assign to a reference **directly**. When it goes through a function or through `static_cast` or `std::move` that prolongation is gone. So you have exactly the same issue with `std::move()`

```
struct sometype {
    sometype() { std::cout << "ctype()" << std::endl; }
    ~sometype() { std::cout << "~ctype()" << std::endl; }
};

const sometype &foobar( const sometype &cref ) { return cref; }

int main()
{
    const sometype &cref1 = foobar( sometype() );
    sometype &&cref2 = std::move( sometype() );
    std::cout << "main continues" << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
ctype()
~ctype()
ctype()
~ctype()
main continues
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/X7H2U0)

Note: you should not use `std::move()` on return statement, it does not give you anything.

For your code change. You should remember that `std::move()` does not move anything. It is done by special assignment operator or constructor (if they provided for a type). So when you write this code:

```
const type &ref = std::move( something );
```

there is no constructor nor assignment operator involved and so no moving happens. For actual moving to happen you have to assign it to a variable:

```
type val = std::move( something );
```

now moving would happen if possible or copy otherwise.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question.  It just shows a better(?) mcve

Comment: That note is not true 100% of the time. Sometimes, `std::move` is required to avoid a copy.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I did not say it is because of a copy, does not matter if copy or not lifetime prolongation is gone, as temporary is an argument for a function and is not directly assigned to a reference. See my example

Comment: I know that `std::move()` doesn't really do anything in the example.  I updated the second example to what I encountered: moving an element out of a `std::list` into a local const reference variable, then deleting that element, and then using the local variable (expecting it to still be valid).

Comment: @Tom I already answered, your temporary is passed to `std::move()` not to reference, so lifetime prolongation is gone. Your new code has different issue - you have dangling reference, you should not jump from code t code like that. This is 2 different cases.

Comment: @Tom: Your code does not "move an element out of a `std::list`", it refers to it in-place.  The `auto f = ...` variant does actually move the content.

Comment: @Slava: What temporary?  We're talking about this line of code, `auto const& f = std::move(l.front());` right?  The only instance of the object lives inside a `std::list` container.  When it is removed from there, all references and pointers to the object become invalid.

Comment: @BenVoigt there was temporary - result of `std::make_shared<>` before OP changed his code.

Comment: I changed the code because some answers pointed out that `std::move` around a function return value is pointless.  Which it is.

Comment: @Tom "I changed the code because some answers pointed out that std::move around a function return value is pointless." you got it wrong. Issue is prolongation does not work because of `std::move()` existance in your original code.

Comment: @Slava, I think I agree with you, that's certainly how it behaves.  But because syntactically `std::move()` appears to be like a function call, I expected lifetime to be prolonged.  It makes sense that it doesn't, after thinking about it.

Comment: @Tom tha's why I showed you that with a function call it does not work either, though some purists do not like my example.

Comment: @Slava: Your example is fine (and I didn't downvote), but I think the complaint is that it is a restatement of the question.

Comment: @Tom: `std::move(x)` isn't just syntactically like a function call, it is a function call.

Comment: @BenVoigt I realize that now.  I accepted this answer because it illustrates the exact same "problem".  Thanks for helping me understand this.