# lifetime extension for function taking parameter by const& and returning by const&

Tags: c++, reference, lifetime

In C++ when you have the following:

```
std::string get_string();
std::string const& v = get_string();
```

The lifetime of the temporary returned from get_string() is extended for the same lifetime of the reference v;

If I have the following:

```
std::string const& get_string(std::string const& p) {
  return p;
}

std::string const& v = 
get_string(std::string{"Hello"});
```

Is the lifetime of the temporary extended? or is this a dangling reference;

My understanding is that the temporary is bound to the lifetime of p 
and that only exists for the duration of the function and that secondary references to the temporary dont extend the lifetime.

What is the expected result?

Comment: This seems to be a much better version of the old https://stackoverflow.com/q/14735630/560648

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the lifetime of the temporary is not extended further more; after the full expression the reference `v` becomes dangled.

```
std::string const& v = get_string(std::string{"Hello"});
// v becomes dangled now
```

> My understanding is that the temporary is bound to the lifetime of p and that only exists for the duration of the function

To be precisely, the [temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) exists until the end of the full expression, not only the duration of the function.

> - a temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call exists until the end of the full expression containing that function call: if the function returns a reference, which outlives the full expression, it becomes a dangling reference.
>
> In general, the lifetime of a temporary cannot be further extended by "passing it on": a second reference, initialized from the reference to which the temporary was bound, does not affect its lifetime.

That means something like `auto sz = get_string(std::string{"Hello"}).size();` is fine.

Comment: So it is because it is bound to p and in the parameter list and there for at the end of the call cant be extended to v. so v is dangling yeah?

Comment: @BlairDavidson I think this way of thinking is right; I added some quotes in my answer.

Comment: The odd thing is this works in gcc so im a bit confused.

Comment: @BlairDavidson Dereference on dangled reference leads to UB; anything is possible. Even it seems working well.

Comment: Is the full expression just right hand side of the assignment operator = or both the left and right side of the assignment operator

Comment: @BlairDavidson Both. From the start to the `;`. :)

Comment: So one possible way to remove the undefined behaviour is to declare v as std::string without the reference.

Comment: Assume these rules are the same for function taking and returning an rvalue reference?

Comment: @BlairDavidson Yes and yes.