# Passing rvalue to const reference behaves oddly when going via longer route

Tags: c++, reference, move-semantics

I have some code where one class (class B) stores another class (class A) by a const lvalue reference. I've done this so I can avoid copying the instance of class A, if I've understood it correctly then even when initialised with an rvalue the const reference can extend the lifetime to that of the variable (and in this case therefore to that of class B).

Using this concept in code demonstrated by this minimal example seems to work:

```
class A
{
    A(int ID); 
};

class B
{
    B(const A &a)
    : m_a{a}
    {}

    B(int ID)
    : m_a{A(ID)}
    {}

    private:
        const A &m_a;
};
```

But, if instead the second constructor for B calls the first, like

```
B(int ID)
: B(A(ID))
{}
```

then I get a load of junk out when I try and access information from class A further down the line, so I guess it's no longer pointing to the object I intended it to?

Why do these two examples perform differently? It seems to me that either way the rvalue instance of class A is being passed to a const reference, only that one route is more direct.

Any insight would be appreciated! Of course I can just use the form that is working, but it would be nice to understand what's going on.

EDIT: I actually get a compiler warning telling me `m_a` will expire outside of the constructor. Adding a std::move around the A(ID) fixed this. It's still worth noting that the code I gave without the standard move works for the duration of the constructor, while the latter starts spitting out garbage even within the constructor still.

Comment: What's `m_a`? Please make a [mre] Also, it would be helpful to show the `main` program that generates the garbage output.

Comment: @cigien Quite obviously the member declaration `a` is a typo...

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Maybe so, but the question still needs editing.

Comment: @cigien By all means...

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14735630/4386278

Comment: sorry, member was supposed to be m_a, not a. Edited accordingly. I could work on making a main to show the behaviour if necessary.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that would be nice. In this case, I think the dupe addresses your question, but in the future, the easier you make it for people to answer your question, the more likely you are to get helped sooner :)

Comment: Yes, I'm satisfied with the answer in the linked question. Thanks everyone!