# Is this example of r-value life time extension dangerous?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code-

Essentially, I'm saving the reference to a value inside a tuple of a class. The global vector is present simply to validate that the address of the variable is the same. At all 3 locations I get the same value for address which indicates that the lifetime of the temporary is extended.

Is this dangerous?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;
template<typename Y>
class dummy
{
public:
    tuple<Y&> tup;
    dummy(Y& y) :tup(y)
    {
        cout << &std::get<0>(tup);  // address 1
    }
};

vector<dummy<int&>> d;
template<typename Y>
void test(Y&& y)
{
    cout<<&y<<"\n"; // address 2
    d.emplace_back(y);
}

int main()
{
    test(123);

    cout << "\n"<<&std::get<0>(d[0].tup); // address 3
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That was my first impression as well. MSVC, gcc and clang worked, so i'm not sure anymore

Comment: temporary created from `123` ends at end of expression `test(123);`. You store dangling reference.

Comment: The lifetime extension only works when *directly* bound to a reference, it cannot be passed on to a different reference. Also, even after the object is destroyed, its address doesn't have to go away.

Comment: *"At all 3 locations I get the same value for address which indicates that the lifetime of the temporary is extended."* -- or which indicates that undefined behavior chose to "simply work". Do you have any indication of the *value* at the address? The value might change if you define another variable after calling `test()`.

Comment: By the way, the output of your program is what you call "address 2" followed by "address 1" then "address 3". If you want the addresses in the order you've numbered them, the output in `test()` should be after the call to `emplace_back()`.

Comment: Loops are a more reliable way to see if a lifetime has been extended (since compilers often reuse storage inside loops). Try `int main()
{ for (int loop = 0; loop < 2; ++loop) { test(loop*loop); }    
std::cout << &std::get<0>(d[0].tup) << ": " << std::get<0>(d[0].tup) << "\n";
std::cout << &std::get<0>(d[1].tup) << ": " << std::get<0>(d[1].tup) << "\n";
}`

Comment: Even better way to check lifetimes: instead of `int`, use a class whose destructor produces output. See, for example, [Which standard wording tells us that ref-to-const temporary lifetime extension only "works once"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735630)

Comment: Thanks @JaMiT. Using actual objects with destructors made it obvious. The references are definitely dangling. The memory just wasn't reused yet.